# How to prevent global variable value of being overwritten with many concurrent connections in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'am new to node.js, came from PHP.

Let's say I have this code:

```
var socket;

function function1(){
    // Does something
}
function function2(){
    // Does something
}
function function3(){
    // Does something
}
```

socket variable is instantiated and set to value when user connects to server. After first user has set value to socket variable, it will stay with that particular value until another user connects and sets another value to variable.

Let's say each function uses this socket variable from the global scope.

For every connected user all 3 functions must execute with exactly same socket value as user set it when connecting to server. How can I prevent socket variable of being overwritten if new users connect faster than all 3 functions  take time to execute for single user?

Is there any better way than passing socket variable to each function?

Comment: Don't use global variables. Point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better way than passing socket variable to each function?

Sure. Just make put the functions in a closure:

```
function newUser(…) {
    var socket;

    function function1(){
        // Does something
    }
    function function2(){
        // Does something
    }
    function function3(){
        // Does something
    }
}
```

Then call `newUser` for every user that is connecting, so that everyone gets his own variable and set of functions to work with it.